# How to print folder and file names in powershell output

Tags: powershell

Here are my dir and files

```
C:\folder1\filename1.pdf
C:\folder2\filename2.pdf
```

I would like to output the following format

```
<root><folder>folder1</folder><file>filename</file></root>
<root><folder>folder2</folder><file>filename</file></root>
```

I'm able to output the full path by the following command.

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*\* -Recurse |
       Foreach-Object {$_.FULLName}{ Convert-Path $_.PSPath }{ ($_.PSPath -split '[\\]')[-1] }
```

This is the output

```
C:\folder1\filename1.pdf
C:\folder2\filename2.pdf
```

How should you approach this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want output like that (resembling XML), you can make use of the properties the returned FileInfo objects have and format which property you like using the `-f` Format operator:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\*\*' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # $_.Directory.Name gives you the directory name of the parent folder
    # $_.DirectoryName  gives the full path to the folder where the file is
    # if you don't want the extension, use $_.BaseName instead of $_.Name
    '<root><folder>{0}</folder><file>{1}</file></root>' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name

    # if you want the whole folder path without the root (C:\), then use
    # $root   = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($_.FullName)
    # $folder = $_.DirectoryName.Substring($root.Length)
    # '<root><folder>{0}</folder><file>{1}</file></root>' -f $folder, $_.Name
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it.